# Countable intersection of intervals forming a singleton

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am tasked to find intervals $[a_n, b_n]$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [a_n,b_n]$ is a singleton and then prove it. I have seen this proof done by my professor using the interval $\left[\frac{n}{n+1}, 1\right]$ and then showing set containment in both ways using the definition of the intersection and Archimedean property, but I was wondering if it could be done in the following way:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the interval $\left[x, x+\frac{1}{n}\right]$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left[x, x+\frac{1}{n}\right] &= \left[x, x+1\right]\cap\left[x, x+\frac{1}{2}\right]...\cap\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[x, x+\frac{1}{n}\right] \\
&= \left[x, x+1\right]\cap\left[x, x+\frac{1}{2}\right]...\cap\,[x, x]\\
&= [x,x] = \{x\} \text{, as desired.}
\end{align*}

I suspect that something goes wrong with the limit part, which wasn't given in any definitions or anything. Clearly, by writing it that way, it shows finitely many intersections, so that's already an issue. I just have the feeling, though, that this *could* be true that I can't shake (despite knowing it *can't* be true).

Comment: If you want to write it out then note that the limit is outside the whole expression: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left([x,x+1]\cap\cdots\cap [x+1/n]\right)$ and it does not make sense to "move it in" (for once there are $n$ sets to be intersected so simply moving the limit to the last factor does not account for this).

Comment: Ah, this makes much more sense! This is what I was trying to express. Is it possible to prove the above statement using this expression?

Comment: Note that $x$ is contained in all of the sets $[x,x+1/k]$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ and is therefore in the intersection. To show that no other point is in the intersection start with any $y\not = x$ and show that if $n$ is large enough then $y$ cannot be in the set $[x,x+1/n]$ and therefore cannot be in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Take $U_n = [-1/n, 1/n], n \ge 1$. Then the countable intersection would be $\{0\}$. can you prove it ? So if you (OP) wants to see the proof, I can write it down in more details as you probably want to see it and compare it with your own. 
Let $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [-1/n,1/n]$,you want to show $A = \{0\}$.So if $x \in A \implies x \in U_n, \forall n \ge 1\implies -1/n \le x \le 1/n, \forall n \ge 1$. Thus taking limit for $n \to \infty$ we have: $x = 0$. This means $A = \{0\}$ as claimed.

Comment: I think I could, but I was specifically wondering if one could prove this by considering, in your case, $\lim_{n\to \infty}[-1/n, 1/n] = [0,0] = \{0\}$.

Comment: To comment on the updated post: this makes sense, thank you! I hadn't thought to write $x$ with inequalities.